# Как сортировать элементы в CheckedListBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть два CheckedListBox. Выбранные элементы переносятся из одного в другой кнопкой. При переносе назад (из CheckedListBox2 в CheckedListBox1) данные не сортируются.

Если установить в настройках Sorted - True, сортировка идет `1,10,11,12,13,2,3,4,5`. Нужно `1,2,3,4,5,10,11,12,13`.

CheckedListBox заполнен данными в конструкторе формы:

> В Visual Studio - конструктор - изменить элементы

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)           
    {
        checkedListBox2.Items.Add(item);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count; i++)  
    {
        checkedListBox1.Items.Remove(checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[i--]);
    }
}
            
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in checkedListBox2.CheckedItems)           
    {
        checkedListBox1.Items.Add(item);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox2.CheckedItems.Count; i++) 
    {
        checkedListBox2.Items.Remove(checkedListBox2.CheckedItems[i--]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Есть код, но он не работает. Все равно идет сортировка 1,10,12,2,3,4..                                                                                                                                                                     List<string> items = new List<string>();
            foreach (string value in checkedListBox1.Items)
            {
                items.Add(value);
            }
            items.Sort();
            checkedListBox1.Items.Clear();
            checkedListBox1.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray());

Comment: А где можно спрашивать?

Answer (score 0):

При добавлении элементов в дизайнере формы они имеют тип `string` (строка).
Соответственно, они сортируются как строки, а не как числа.

Решить это можно разными способами.
Первый: парсим элементы, преобразуя их в числа. Затем числа сортируем.

```
var items = new List<int>();

foreach (string value in checkedListBox.Items)
{
    int number = int.Parse(value);
    items.Add(number);
}

items.Sort();
checkedListBox.Items.Clear();

foreach (int n in items)
    checkedListBox.Items.Add(n);
```

Обратите внимание, что после этого значения в `CheckedListBox.Items` имеют тип `int`. Возможно, вам для дальнейшей работы нужны именно строки, тогда в последней строке кода нужно преобразовать числа в `string`:

```
checkedListBox2.Items.Add(n.ToString());
```

---

Другой способ. Занести числа в `CheckedListBox` не в дизайнере, а в коде.
Делаем это в событии `Load`:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    checkedListBox2.Items.Add(22);
    checkedListBox2.Items.Add(21);
    checkedListBox2.Items.Add(2);
    checkedListBox2.Items.Add(1);
    checkedListBox2.Items.Add(12);
    checkedListBox2.Items.Add(11);
}
```

При этом `CheckedListBox` в дизайнере должен быть полностью очищен от элементов!

Теперь при осуществлении сортировки изменять тип не нужно:

```
var items = new List<int>();

foreach (int value in checkedListBox2.Items)
    items.Add(value);

items.Sort();
checkedListBox2.Items.Clear();

foreach (int n in items)
    checkedListBox2.Items.Add(n);
```

---

Свойство `Sorted` в обоих случаях должно быть установлено в `false`.

Comment: Второй метод работает) Большое спасибо!